# python argparse ignore other options when a specific option is used

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am writing a python program that I want to have a command line interface that behaves in a particular way

The command line interface should accept the following invocations:

```
my_prog test.svg foo
my_prog --font=Sans test.svg foo
```

(it will generate an svg with the word `foo` written in the specified or default font)

Now I want to be able to also have this command accept the following invocation...

```
my_prog --list-fonts
```

which will list all of the valid options to `--font` as determined by the fonts available on the system.

I am using `argparse`, and I have something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('output_file')
parser.add_argument('text')
parser.add_argument('--font', help='list options with --list-fonts')
parser.add_argument('--list-fonts', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

however this does not make the `--list-fonts` option behave as I would like as the two positional arguments are still required.

I have also tried using subparsers, but these still need a workaround to prevent the other options being required every time.

How do I get the desired behaviour with argparse.

Comment: If you had one positional with `nargs='*'` it should accept all the alternatives.  After parsing you could check whether the positional has the right number of strings or not, and raise an error as necessary (or ignore unneeded values).  Otherwise I think you have to go the custom `Action` route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

argparse allows you to define arbitrary actions to take when encountering an argument, based on the `action` keyword argument to `add_argument` ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action))

You can define an action to list your fonts and then abort argument parsing, which will avoid checking for the other required arguments.

this could look like this:

```
class ListFonts(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        print("list of fonts here")
        parser.exit() # exits the program with no more arg parsing and checking
```

Then you can add it to your argument like so:

```
parser.add_argument('--list-fonts', nargs=0, action=ListFonts)
```

Note `nargs=0` has been added so that this argument doesn't require a value (the code in the question achieved this with `action='store_true'`)

This solution has a side-effect of enabling the invocations like the following to also list the fonts and exits without running the main program:

```
my_prog --font Sans test.svg text --list-fonts
```

This is likely not a problem as it's not a typical use case, especially if the help text explains this behaviour.

If defining a new class for each such option feels too heavyweight, or perhaps you have more than one option that has this behaviour, then you could consider having a function that implements the desired action for each argument and then have a kind of factory function that returns a class that wraps the function. A complete example of this is shown below.

```
def list_fonts():
    print("list of fonts here")

def override(func):
    """ returns an argparse action that stops parsing and calls a function
    whenever a particular argument is encountered. The program is then exited """
    class OverrideAction(argparse.Action):
        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
            func()
            parser.exit()
    return OverrideAction

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('output_file')
parser.add_argument('text')
parser.add_argument('--font', help='list options with --list-fonts')
parser.add_argument('--list-fonts', nargs=0, action=override(list_fonts),
    help='list the font options then stop, don\'t generate output')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a test mode option (--test) to my script and wanted to ignore the other, normally required, parameters when --test was specified. To do so I used your snippet, but extended argparse._StoreTrueAction instead of argparse.Action (for action='store_true'-like behavior). Then I added a custom exception and caught that during the call to parse_args().